# Sorting Array of Struct's based on String

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

I've been reading all the topics related to sorting arrays of structs, but haven't had any luck as of yet, so I'll just ask. I have a struct:

```
  struct question{
    string programNum;
    string programDesc;
    string programPoints;
    string programInput;
    string programQuestion;
  };
```

And I populate an array of `question` in main, and now have an array called `questions[]` so now I need to write a sort that will sort `questions[]` based on `question.programQuestion`. Based on what I've read, this is where I'm at, but I'm not sure if its even close:

```
int myCompare (const void *v1, const void *v2 ) {
     const struct question* p1 = static_cast<const struct question*>(v1);
     const struct question* p2 = static_cast<const struct question*>(v2);
     if (p1->programQuestion > p2->programQuestion){
          return(+1);}
     else if (p1->programQuestion < p2->programQuestion){
          return(-1);}
     else{
    return(0);}
     }
```

If this is right I'm not sure how to call it in main. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yours might possibly be right if you plan on call the C qsort routine, which I desperately hope you are not. Please use the std::sort from <algorithm> and follow ones of the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're intending to use `std::sort` to sort this array, you likely want to declare an `operator<` as a method in this `struct`.  Something like this:

```
  struct question{
    string programNum;
    string programDesc;
    string programPoints;
    string programInput;
    string programQuestion;

    bool operator<( const question &rhs) const;
  };

  bool question::operator<( const question &rhs ) const
  {
      return programQuestion < rhs.programQuestion;
  }
```

The comparison function you were attempting to declare above appears to be the type `qsort` expects, and I would *not* recommend trying to `qsort` an array of these `struct question`s.

Just use `std::sort`.  It's safer, nearly always faster (sometimes by huge margins), and generally easier to get right.

Comment: Yea it was going to be qsort, I had done one that worked on some integer values. I've never done one comparing strings though, so you think I should use a regular sort()?

Comment: Yes, just use regular `sort()`.  It's faster, safer and more flexible than `qsort()`.

Comment: Always use `std::sort`. its generally faster as it can inline the sort function while `qsort` relies on function pointers which can't be inlined at compile time.

Comment: The only use case of `qsort` is when `std::sort` is not available (in  C or your compiler lack STL).

Comment: So how would I call the sort in main with the above code? I get that the operator function will compare question.programQuestion with rhs but I'm not sure how the call is made?

Comment: @user2990286 :  `std::sort( array, array + len )` should do it for a plain array.  If you switch to a `std::vector`, then `std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() )`, assuming you named your vector `v`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is some important reason not to do so, I would use a `std::vector` instead of a plain array. It is easier and safer. You could use the following code to sort your vector:

```
std::vector<question> questions;

// add some elements to the vector

std::sort(begin(questions), end(questions),
    [](const question& q1, const question& q2) {
        return q1.programQuestion < q2.programQuestion;
    });
```

This code use some C++11 features. But you could achieve the same in previous versions of C++ by using a [function object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B), or simply by implementing `operator<` in the struct (assuming you always want to sort such a struct based on that field).

Comment: Just throwing my own $0.02 here:  A lambda makes sense if you're using a locally-defined sorting criteria (and you have C++11 support).  An `operator<` makes more sense if it defines the intrinsic ordering for the class.  (ie. the ordering is a canonical ordering for objects of this class and is therefore meaningful outside the scope of the sort immediately at hand.)

Comment: the vector bit tho is superfluous, he can call std::sort on an array just fine.

Comment: @JoeZ Yes, that's what I mean in my last paragraph. If the OP intends to sort questions based on the same criteria, it is definitely better to implement `operator<` in the struct. If more flexibility is required, the lambda approach fits better.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett `std::sort` works for plain arrays. But in most cases it is preferrable to use a `std::vector` than a plain array. Not everyone is aware of that.